# sublime text 3 package control install

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I have a problem when I install the package control of sublime text 3 because of the proxy set but I need to install a plugin. When I do `getproxy` in the console it returns me {} and when I try to set the proxy with python in console with

`urllib.set_proxy('http://user:password@server:port', 'http')`

I replaced the user, password, server and port by their values but it returns me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_proxy'
```

what can I do to make it work? I need to install a plugin .

Answer (score 14):

#### Setting Up Package Control to Work from Behind a Proxy Server

You will need to setup your proxy server in the `Package Control` settings.

Copy and paste the code below into a file called `Package Control.sublime-settings` which must be saved in your `User` config folder. That is the same folder as your **USER** `Preferences.sublime-settings` file is saved in. [The Data Directory](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) states where this is on your operating system. i.e.

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Package Control.sublime-settings`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings`
- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings`

Clearly you must add the domain and port and your user name and password in the relevant fields below. The proxy should be in the form: `proxyserver:port`. e.g.

```
{
    "http_proxy": "server.com:80",
    "https_proxy": "server.com:8080",
    "proxy_username": "mynameis",
    "proxy_password": "mypassis",
}
```

See also: [Package Control Settings](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/settings)

```
{
    // An HTTP proxy server to use for requests. Not normally used on Windows
    // since the system proxy configuration is utilized via WinINet. However,
    // if WinINet is not working properly, this will be used by the Urllib
    // downloader, which acts as a fallback.
    "http_proxy": "",

    // An HTTPS proxy server to use for requests - this will inherit from
    // http_proxy if it is set to "" or null and http_proxy has a value. You
    // can set this to false to prevent inheriting from http_proxy. Not
    // normally used on Windows since the system proxy configuration is
    // utilized via WinINet. However, if WinINet is not working properly, this
    // will be used by the Urllib downloader, which acts as a fallback.
    "https_proxy": "",

    // Username and password for both http_proxy and https_proxy. May be used
    // with WinINet to set credentials for system-level proxy config.
    "proxy_username": "",
    "proxy_password": "",
}
```

Comment: Any idea whether we can configure a proxy url instead ("automatic configuration script"?

Comment: @Mugen I'm not sure, I thought a proxy url was just used in a web browser, but I could be wrong. If no luck finding out here try posting in the [Technical Support forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/c/technical-support) on the Sublime Text site.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply run the below command in the Sublime 3 console (launch console using `` CTRL+` ``  or `View -> Show Console`)

```
import urllib.request,os; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT', 'https': 'https://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT'})) ); open(os.path.join(ipp, pf), 'wb').write(urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())
```

In the above code, you need to replace the value(`USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT`) of `http` and `https` keys as per your proxy details

Then hit `Enter` and it will install the `Package Control` using the provided proxy

Comment: What that sublime.wbond.net domain is? Looks suspecious.

Answer (score 4):

I exactly had the same issue, I was unable to download packages for Sublime Text 3. I set up the proxy server at runtime as shown in below snippet in the Sublime console (Mac Shortcut Ctrl + `) and it worked for me.

```
import os
proxy_server = 'http://username:password@proxy_server_name:port'
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy_server
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy_server
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy_server
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy_server
os.environ['all_proxy'] = proxy_server
os.environ['ALL_PROXY'] = proxy_server
os.environ['ftp_proxy'] = proxy_server
os.environ['FTP_PROXY'] = proxy_server
```

Answer (score 0):

### for `socks5` proxy settings:

menubar: `Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings`

NOTE: `curl` downloadder backend support `socks5`.

```json
{
    
    "downloader_precedence": {
        "linux": ["curl"]
    },
    "http_proxy": "socks5://127.0.0.1:1080",
    "proxy_password": "",
    "proxy_username": "",
...
```