# Setting up a Proxy on Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, http-proxy

I am trying to set up a proxy on sublime to download packages.
I have tried following the steps in the question [sublime text 3 package control install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476308/sublime-text-3-package-control-install)

However, I am not clear on where this should be done.
Here are my steps

1. Open Sublime
2. Click on Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control
3. Two windows open up with the same file name `Package Control.sublime-settings`
4. I am not able to edit the window on the left. I can edit the window on the right
5. I post in the following into the window on the right with actual proxies

```
{
    "bootstrapped": true,
    /*"in_process_packages":
    [
    ],*/
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "Package Control"
    ],
},

{
    // An HTTP proxy server to use for requests. Not normally used on Windows
    // since the system proxy configuration is utilized via WinINet. However,
    // if WinINet is not working properly, this will be used by the Urllib
    // downloader, which acts as a fallback.
    "http_proxy": "",

    // An HTTPS proxy server to use for requests - this will inherit from
    // http_proxy if it is set to "" or null and http_proxy has a value. You
    // can set this to false to prevent inheriting from http_proxy. Not
    // normally used on Windows since the system proxy configuration is
    // utilized via WinINet. However, if WinINet is not working properly, this
    // will be used by the Urllib downloader, which acts as a fallback.
    "https_proxy": "",

    // Username and password for both http_proxy and https_proxy. May be used
    // with WinINet to set credentials for system-level proxy config.
    "proxy_username": "",
    "proxy_password": "",
}
```

When i restart sublime I get the following error and all the updates automatically are commented out

> Unexpected trailing characters...

I am a complete newbie to this but any help would be really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The settings file needs to be valid JSON. That means, among other things, that everything needs to be part of one big array, defined by curly braces `{}`. Delete lines 10-12:

```json
},

{
```

and it will be valid.